# Change device language on Android 6.0 (Android M)

Tags: android, localization, internationalization, adb

There are applications to change Android device language (locale) via an ADB command. This has required granting the CHANGE_CONFIGURATION permission for the app before language can be changed.

On Android 6.0 (API level 23, Nexus 6 device), however, granting the required permission is no longer allowed, since the command `adb shell pm grant net.sanapeli.adbchangelanguage android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION` (package name from [ADB Change Language app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sanapeli.adbchangelanguage) as an example) yields

> Operation not allowed: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION is not a changeable permission type

How can you change the language/locale on Android OS version 6.0 *without rooting the device*? Can this be done with a helper app, or a direct ADB command, or by launching some intent vai ADB?

Related question from 2010: [Change language programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programatically-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SecurityException no longer exists on the public image of Android OS 6.0 (Marshmallow) version. This was confirmed on Nexus 6 and Nexus 9 devices. Case closed.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by putting my app in /system/priv-app, so it becomes a privileged system app. As root:

```
mount -o remount,rw /system
mkdir /system/priv-app/MyApp
cp /sdcard/myapp.apk /system/priv-app/MyApp/MyApp.apk
chcon "u:object_r:system_file:s0" /system/priv-app/MyApp
chcon "u:object_r:system_file:s0" /system/priv-app/MyApp/MyApp.apk
mount -o remount,ro /system
```

Chcon sets the proper SELinux security context.

Comment: the purpose of the app is to provide the ability to control the locale on a stock production (i.e. unrooted) device. on a rooted device why bother with the app?

Comment: Thanks, but I really can't use this solution if I have to root my device. I edited my question, asking how to do this without rooting.